# URLSessionConfiguration Background download task fails when device is locked with error - Lost connection to background transfer service

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm getting a

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service"

when I lock my screen after starting a background download process. I'm using Alamofire but I assume this would happen on a regular URLSession as well. The downloads continue to work if I soft close the app but as soon as I lock my device, it start throwing this error.

Here's the relevant part of code:

```
private(set) lazy var alamoSessionManager: SessionManager = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MySession")
    config.isDiscretionary = true
    config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
    config.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true
    return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: config)
}()

let route = buildRouter()

alamoSessionManager.request(url, method: route.method, parameters: route.parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: route.headers)
```

I looked at the Console to see if any daemon crashed but couldn't find any. I see three errors right after locking the screen:

> BKLogEvent: couldn't find CombinedSequence properties
>
> Task <>.<48> finished with error - code: -999
>
> Task <>.<48> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=Lost connection to background transfer service} [-997]

The error._userInfo is this:

```
▿ Optional<AnyObject>
  ▿ some : 5 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : NSErrorFailingURLStringKey
      - value : https://www.myweb.com/api
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : NSErrorFailingURLKey
      - value : https://www.myweb.com/api
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey
      ▿ value : 2 elements
        - 0 : BackgroundDataTask <C39E-2FC73>.<27>
        - 1 : LocalDataTask <C39E-2FC73>.<27>
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - key : _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey
      - value : BackgroundDataTask <C39E-2FC73>.<27>
    ▿ 4 : 2 elements
      - key : NSLocalizedDescription
      - value : Lost connection to background transfer service
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the iOS documentation correctly, `alamoSessionManager.request` will not work in the background, only `alamoSessionManager.download` and `alamoSessionManager.upload` only will work.

When you use `alamoSessionManager.download` JSON response will be download and saved in a tmp file. Make sure to move to a permanent place and read the file and convert it to `JSONDecoder` object. Let me know , if you are not clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire isn't really compatible with background sessions at the moment, both due to the inability to persist and reconnect its closure APIs, as well as the fact that it `invalidateAndCancel()` the `URLSession` when it's `deinit`d. We recommend you use `URLSession` directly for background session, or use foreground sessions with the background task API.

Comment: It does not work with URLSession, you get exactly same error. Maybe you know the real root cause?